# SQL Query - Where at least two of one value AND 1 positive and negative of a second

Tags: sql

I'm struggling with an SQL Query here. I'm trying to:

```
SELECT

 Name, Check, Amount

FROM

 TableName, TableCheck, TableAmount

WHERE

    There are at least TWO of Check from Table Check

    AND

    There is at least one positive AND one negative of Amount from TableAmount
```

For example, there would be an assorted set of names in names, check would be a random number between 1 and 5,  Amount would be a number between say -500 and 500.

If the below exists, both would be returned.

```
Name: Jim - Check: 3 -  Amount: 258
Name: Jim - Check: 3 -  Amount: -127
```

I just want it to return all of the applicable values that fulfill the `WHERE` statement above. As for the example, say there was *also* another Jim, but with a check of 4. It would not be returned in the `SELECT` unless there was another check of 4 which also helped fulfill the need of separate (negative and positive) amounts.

Comment: Perhaps use `EXISTS` clauses to check whether those conditions exist.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: look up the HAVING clause also.

Comment: `min(amt) * max(amt) < 0`

Comment: As posted there just isn't anywhere near enough information for anybody to be able to offer much here other than guesses. There are no details about your tables, business rules or what you want to retrieve. In essence you really haven't actually posted a question yet. All is not lost however. This will be a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I do have to wonder why this is three tables. At a minimum, TableCheck and TableAmount should be one table, unless you have checks written for more than one amount simultaneously. TableName could be the Customers table equivalent, so that one separated out is fine.

Comment: There are plenty more tables actually, and a hundred more columns, but this was the way I could express it at its simplest. Given what I need for this query.

Comment: [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a derived table to identify the names that match your criteria:

```
SELECT
    Name, 
    Check, 
    Amount
FROM TableName tn
INNER JOIN TableCheck tc
    ON tn.nameID = tc.nameID
INNER JOIN TableAmount ta
    ON tc.checkID = ta.CheckID
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        tk.nameID, 
        Count(Distinct tk.CheckID) as ckCount,
        Min(tt.Amount) as MinAmt,
        max(tt.amount) as maxAmount
    FROM TableCheck tk
    INNER JOIN tableAmount tt
        ON tk.CheckID = tt.CheckID
    GROUP BY tk.NameID
    HAVING Count(Distinct tk.CheckID) >=2
        AND MinAmt < 0
        AND MaxAmt > 0
    ) f
    ON f.NameID = tn.NameID
```